# How to set linux as default OS after reinstalling windows already dual booted envirnment?

Tags: linux

I have a system running windows and linux in dual boot envirnment. But due to of some problem i have reinstall my windows but now my boot menu only shows windows OS.
I want to know that how i can again reset my system's boot menu as it shows after installing linux over windows i.e. boot menu shows both OS.
Or we can say how i set my boot menu default OS linux again.

Comment: ...this is not a security question.

Comment: In my experience the easiest way to restore the Linux bootloader is to run the [boot-repair Live CD](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/). However, this question has nothing to do with infosec and would probably be more appropriate on SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

This is off-topic. Also you should tell us which Linux distro you are talking about (eg. there is wubi for Ubuntu, which make use of Windows' boot loader and is present within the partition Windows NTFS).

In the terminal do:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```